# Can't get my code to move elements back from one unordered list to another using an "addEventListner"

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, addeventlistener

I've created a to-do-list. The user can write down a list of tasks they want to complete for the day. Once the tasks have been completed they can tick the checkbox, which "trigger" a line-trough. Then the tasks move from the unordered list with id "uList" to the unordered list with id "taskCompleted". However, I want the user to be able to move an item, which is in the latter back into the former, just by double clicking on it. The tasks will have to be presented in their original "state". Namely no line-through and an unticked checkbox. I've used the event object and now I'm using a for loop, in order to do so. However, both attempts have failed. I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

```js
var elUlList = document.getElementById("uList");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const elInput = document.getElementById("input");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const elCounter = document.getElementById("counter");
const taskCompleted = document.getElementById("taskCompleted");
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

function createListItems() {
  var inputValue = elInput.value;
  if(inputValue === "" || inputValue === null) return

  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.id = Date.now().toString();
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "checkbox";
  input.name = "to-do-input";
  var newText = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  newLi.appendChild(input);
  newLi.appendChild(newText);
  elUlList.appendChild(newLi);
  elCounter.innerHTML =+ elements.length;

  var toDoInput = document.getElementsByTagName("to-do-input");

  for(var i = 0; i < toDoInput.length; i++) {
    toDoInput[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      if(e.target.checked == true) {
        e.target.parentNode.remove();
      }
    })
  }
  }

btn.addEventListener("click", createListItems, false);

elInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.click()
  }
})

elInput.addEventListener("mouseover", emptyField, false)

function emptyField() {
  this.value = "";
}

elUlList.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  alert("are you sure you want to move this item to completed task");
  parent.classList.add("taskMoved");
  taskCompleted.appendChild(parent);
  elCounter.innerHTML =+ elements.length;
});


elUlList.addEventListener("click", strikeOutElement, false);


function strikeOutElement(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if(target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")){
  target.closest("li").classList.toggle("lineThrough", target.checked);
  }
}

var taskMoved = document.getElementsByClassName("taskMoved");

if(taskMoved.length > 0) {
  for(var i = 0; i < taskMoved.length; i++) {
    taskMoved[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    taskMoved[i].classList.remove("lineThrough");
    taskMoved[i].firstElementChild.toggle("lineThrough", target.checked);
    taskMoved[i].firstElementChild.checked = false;
    elUlList.appendChild(taskMoved[i]);
  }, false);
  }
}
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US")

footer.innerHTML = date
console.log(date)
```

```css
.greenColor {
  color: green;
}

.redColor {
  color: red;
}

.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="message"class=""></div>
  <ul id="uList"></ul>
  <button id="btn" type="button" name="button">click here to add items</button><br>
  <input id="input" type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="counter" class=""></div>
  <p>task Completed</p>
  <ul id="taskCompleted"></ul>

  <footer></footer>


    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a lot of looping over global variables and adding eventlisteners all the time. I tried to clean that up a bit, with one function that creates a task with only 2 listeners that keep on working.

```js
const tasksTodo = document.getElementById("uList");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const elInput = document.getElementById("input");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const elCounter = document.getElementById("counter");
const tasksCompleted = document.getElementById("taskCompleted");
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

function createTask(input) {
  let title = input.value;
  if ( !title ) return false;
  let task = document.createElement("li");
  let checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  task.appendChild(checkbox);
  task.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));

  //Checkbox is source of truth, listen to it changing
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
      if (checkbox.checked)
        completeTask(task);
      else
        undoTask(task);
  });
  tasksTodo.appendChild(task);
  //Then let dblclick just toggle the box
  task.addEventListener("dblclick", e =>{checkbox.click()});
  //reset the input, we're done
  input.value = '';
}

function completeTask(task) {
  task.classList.add("lineThrough");
  tasksCompleted.appendChild(task);
}

function undoTask(task) {
  task.classList.remove("lineThrough");
  tasksTodo.appendChild(task);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", e=>{createTask(elInput)}, false);
elInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.click();
  }
});

var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");

footer.innerHTML = date
console.log(date)
```

```css
.greenColor {
  color: green;
}

.redColor {
  color: red;
}

.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practise App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="message" class=""></div>
  <ul id="uList"></ul>
  <button id="btn" type="button" name="button">click here to add items</button><br>
  <input id="input" type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="counter" class=""></div>
  <p>task Completed</p>
  <ul id="taskCompleted"></ul>

  <footer></footer>


  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```